# ACF content is empty in fancybox

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fancybox, advanced-custom-fields

I have ACF set up to be called into a fancybox. It's pulling in the fields (because I can see the hardcoded header information) but nothing from the ACF. I've set the link to call an ID which is then assigned to the section I want to call when clicked.

I expect to click the image and open the fancy box with the ACF image and content displaying in the fancybox. What I get is header fields and no acf content.

I've tried removing the display none from the class.

I tried hard coding a basic a tag calling a p and that seemed to work, but when I put in the ACF information, it breaks.

I also removed all of the php and just hard coded in an image and content, and it works. It just doesn't like the php calling my ACF.

```
<a href="#popup" data-fancybox>               
            <img class="image" src="<?php the_field('project_image', get_the_ID()); ?>" />
        </a>
<section id="popup">
            <img src="<?php the_field('project_image', get_the_ID()); ?>">
                    <h3>About</h3>
                    <p><?php echo $about_content;?></p>
                        <hr class="hr-left">
                        <h3>Features</h3>
                    <p><?php echo $features_content; ?></p>
                    <a class="btn secondary-btn" href="<?php echo $code_reference_url; ?>"><?php echo $button_text; ?></a>
</section>
```

When the image is clicked, a fancy box will open and display the content within the "popup" div. What's happening is that it's opening the lightbox and populating with empty fields.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this. I didn't have the information operating inside the loop. See solution below:

```
<?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                $about_content = get_field('about_content');
                $features_content = get_field('features_content');
                $button_text = get_field('button_text');
            ?>
```